# VideoView doesn't load Video from internal storage

Tags: android, android-videoview, kotlin-android-extensions, android-fileprovider

VideoView won't load video from internal storage. I first save a copy of this video to internal storage and later when I try to load video using setVideoURI(), nothing happens.

The code to setVideoURI

```
val videoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext,"com.bruhascended.sms.fileProvider", File(path))
mContext.grantUriPermission("com.bruhascended.sms", videoUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
video.setVideoURI(videoUri)
```

The code where I save the file to the appplication's internal storage.

```
fun saveMedia(date: Long): String {
    val name = date.toString() + "." + MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getExtensionFromMimeType(typeString)
    val destination = File(mContext.filesDir, name)
    val output: OutputStream = FileOutputStream(destination)
    val input = mContext.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)!!
    val buffer = ByteArray(4 * 1024)
    var read: Int
    while (input.read(buffer).also { read = it } != -1) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, read)
    }
    output.flush()
    return destination.toString()
}
```

And file provider in manifest

```
<provider
       android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
       android:authorities="com.bruhascended.sms.fileProvider"
       android:exported="false"
       android:grantUriPermissions="true">
       <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" 
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

and lastly file_paths.xml

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="media" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Comment: "The code to setVideoURI" -- that is not where your video is. Your video is in `File(mContext.filesDir, name)`. Use [`setVideoPath()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView?hl=en#setVideoPath(java.lang.String)), passing in the filesystem path for your file (e.g., `getAbsolutePath()` on your `File`).

Comment: @CommonsWare The "path" variable contains the absolute path of my video file returned by the saveMedia() function. I have also tried setVideoPath(path), which doesn't work either.
Edit: I used this path to get MimeType and that is working normally so pretty sure the problem is not with the path.